# ovirt change export path

Tags: rhev, ovirt

I have 3 NICs in all of my machines.  All NFS traffic should be going across the second NIC, but I accidentally set up one of my data stores using the first NIC.  Is it possible to change the export path to use the second NIC?  It would just be a matter of changing the IP, but it won't let me edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the SD edit feature. The admin guide mentions it and here is the detailed explanation http://www.ovirt.org/Features/Manage_Storage_Connections

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to halt all of the guests that were on that mount (I probably could have suspended or migrated them), and then put the volume into maintenance, and it let me edit the hostname.